# How to properly works in Chrome as a Drupal administrator?

Tags: performance

Not sure if is there I can do from the Drupal side, then I'll close this question if not suitable here...

I use Chrome to admin my drupal sites and I noticed that after some hours (let's say 3 or 4 hours) the site start to take more time to load admin pages. I resolve this by clearing the Chrome cache. This is ok but then I loss all stored data in Chrome.

Is there I should do within the drupal configuration to avoid this?

Comment: You can use dev tools to find the problem - clear Chrome's cache, and take a snapshot of network throughput. Use the site as normal for a while, and when it slows back down, take another snapshot. Compare the two and you'll see which requests are causing the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clearing the chrome cache it will ask for some options(shows a dialogue box with checkboxes), there you only need to check the **Empty the cache** checkbox and uncheck all other checkboxes and then click on **Clear browsing data**. Then it will only clear your browser cache not all chrome data.
[image]